# "App.auth" is no a function error in AngularFire

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I've scoured the web and tried almost all hacks to solve this issue.

```
Uncaught TypeError: app.auth is not a function
    at angular-fire-auth.js:42
```

The devs are even nice enough to comment about it:

[image]

Still no luck... every single time I have to delete node_modules folder and npm install for things to work.

This is my auth service:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
...
constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
...
}


 async continueWithSocial(authProvider: string) {
    let oAuthProvider: any;
    if (authProvider === "google") {
      oAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    } else if (authProvider === "facebook") {
      oAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    }
    ...
}

continueWithEmail(email: string, password: string) {
    let response = this.firebaseAuth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(...)
    ...
}

...
```

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Still not clear what is the issue, is it being caused by some method call from angularfire `AngularFireAuth` ?

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this issue myself since firebase version ^7.17.0. Downgrading firebase to ^7.16.0 seems to resolve the issue.